# How do I search for a Tag in xml file using ElementTree where i have a certain "Parent"tag with a specific value? (python)

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath, elementtree

I just started learning Python and have to write a program, that parses xml files. I have to find a certain Tag called OrganisationReference in 2 different files and return it. In fact there are multiple Tags with this name, but only one, the one I am trying to return, that has the Tag OrganisationType with the value DEALER as a parent Tag (not quite sure whether the term is right). I tried to use ElementTree for this. Here is the code:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    tree1 = ET.parse('Master1.xml')
    root1 = tree1.getroot()

    tree2 = ET.parse('Master2.xml')
    root2 = tree2.getroot()

    for OrganisationReference in root1.findall("./Organisation/OrganisationId/[@OrganisationType='DEALER']/OrganisationReference"):
        print(OrganisationReference.attrib)

    for OrganisationReference in root2.findall("./Organisation/OrganisationId/[@OrganisationType='DEALER']/OrganisationReference"):
        print(OrganisationReference.attrib)
```

But this returns nothing (also no error). Can  somebody help me?

My file looks like this:

```
  <MessageOrganisationCount>a</MessageOrganisationCount>
  <MessageVehicleCount>x</MessageVehicleCount>
  <MessageCreditLineCount>y</MessageCreditLineCount>
  <MessagePlanCount>z</MessagePlanCount>
  <OrganisationData>
      <Organisation>
          <OrganisationId>
              <OrganisationType>DEALER</OrganisationType>
              <OrganisationReference>WHATINEED</OrganisationReference>
          </OrganisationId>
          <OrganisationName>XYZ.</OrganisationName>
 ....
```

Due to the fact that OrganisationReference appears a few more times in this file with different text between start and endtag, I want to get exactly the one, that you see in line 9: it has OrganisationId as a parent tag, and DEALER is also a child tag of OrganisationId.

Comment: How can this be reproduced? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide an example of your XML-File and what your output should look like

Comment: I edited my post, now you can see how my xml file looks like.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Jani! Great first question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were super close with your original attempt. You just need to make a couple of changes to your xpath and a tiny change to your python.

The first part of your xpath starts with `./Organization`. Since you're doing the xpath from root, it expects `Organization` to be a child. It's not; it's a descendant.

Try changing `./Organization` to `.//Organization`. (`//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. [See here for more info.](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev))

The second issue is with `OrganisationId/[@OrganisationType='DEALER']`. That's invalid xpath. The `/` should be removed from between `OrganisationId` and the [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates).

Also, `@` is abbreviated syntax for the `attribute::` [axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes) and `OrganisationType` is an element, not an attribute.

Try changing `OrganisationId/[@OrganisationType='DEALER']` to `OrganisationId[OrganisationType='DEALER']`.

The python issue is with `print(OrganisationReference.attrib)`. The `OrganisationReference` doesn't have any attributes; just text.

Try changing `print(OrganisationReference.attrib)` to `print(OrganisationReference.text)`.

Here's an example using just one XML file for demo purposes...

**XML Input** (Master1.xml; with `doc` element added to make it well-formed)

```xml
<doc>
    <MessageOrganisationCount>a</MessageOrganisationCount>
    <MessageVehicleCount>x</MessageVehicleCount>
    <MessageCreditLineCount>y</MessageCreditLineCount>
    <MessagePlanCount>z</MessagePlanCount>
    <OrganisationData>
        <Organisation>
            <OrganisationId>
                <OrganisationType>DEALER</OrganisationType>
                <OrganisationReference>WHATINEED</OrganisationReference>
            </OrganisationId>
            <OrganisationName>XYZ.</OrganisationName>
        </Organisation>
    </OrganisationData>
</doc>
```

**Python**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree1 = ET.parse('Master1.xml')
root1 = tree1.getroot()

for OrganisationReference in root1.findall(".//Organisation/OrganisationId[OrganisationType='DEALER']/OrganisationReference"):
    print(OrganisationReference.text)
```

**Printed Output**

```
WHATINEED
```

---

Also note that it doesn't appear that you need to use `getroot()` at all. You can use `findall()` directly on the tree...

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree1 = ET.parse('Master1.xml')

for OrganisationReference in tree1.findall(".//Organisation/OrganisationId[OrganisationType='DEALER']/OrganisationReference"):
    print(OrganisationReference.text)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is a nametag in the xml file. With considering them in the code it wokrs perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested for-loop to do it. First you check whether the text of `OrganisationType` is DEALER and then get the text of the `OrganisationReference` that you need.

If you want to learn more about parsing XML with Python I strongly recommend the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) of the XMLtree library.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree1 = ET.parse('Master1.xml')
root1 = tree1.getroot()

tree2 = ET.parse('Master2.xml')
root2 = tree2.getroot()

#Find the parent Dealer
for element in root1.findall('./Organisation/OrganisationId'):
    if element[0].text == "DEALER":
         print(element[1].text)
```

This works if the first tag in your OrganisationId is OrganisationType :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers.I'm new to Python, thats why I probably mixed the terms up: Dealer is the text of an element. I'm very sorry for this confusion.  @Jones1220

Comment: No it still returns nothing